# Where is the MongoDB integration with Splunk's Hunk?

Tags: mongodb, splunk, bigdata

I've been looking into NoSQL integration for Splunk using Hunk but there seems to be virtually no documentation on this process?

Is it possible? Are there docs?

I'm using Hunk 6.1

Specifically I am trying to use MongoDB as a backend datastore to splunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer, is likely that there is no other NoSQL integrations out of the box and you'll have to roll your own for now.

Hunk has been marketed widely as Splunk for Hadoop and that is their first use case. (This can be seen in the [Developer PDF still](http://dev.splunk.com/web_assets/pdfs/secure/Hunk_for_Developers.pdf). General user documentation can be found http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Hunk/latest.

But the design of Hunk is that you define a "Virtual Index" that instead of connecting to and querying data from Splunk's built in indexes, you connect externally to another NoSQL data store. This requires a library to make requests to the NoSQL store and stream results back to Splunk (as can be seen in the [diagram on this page](http://dev.splunk.com/view/get-started/SP-CAAAEUA))

I would suspect that they may expand the virtual index concept and ship libraries for other NoSQL datastores in the future as they have demand, but for now they have provided an example app that reportedly has documentation inside the app itself guide you on how to roll your own connecting library: http://apps.splunk.com/app/1802/

Answer (score 0):

This functionality now exists with Hunk and the Hunk App for MongoDB.  Here is the announcement : http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/splunks-hunk-powerful-way-visualize-your-data-stored-mongodb

The app is available here: https://apps.splunk.com/app/1810/

I hope that helps!